# How to copy file from remote host to jenkins server

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins for build process. I am running some scripts on remote server using jenkins server. It's fine but remote host generates some html file. I want to copy that file back to jenkins server. Is it possible to do it from jenkins server?

Comment: Just compy these files over ssh if applicable using shell script as a build step. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21259811/1361089

Answer (score 2):

If you want to archive it permanently, you can use the `Archive Artifacts` option in the `Post-build` step in Jenkins.  In the case of builds that happen on slaves, `Archive Artifacts` copies the artifacts back to the Jenkins server for archiving and reuse.

If you want to then use this in a subsequent build, you can use the `Copy Artifacts` step to introduce an artifact from another build into your subsequent process on any Jenkins slave.

We use this to move production builds into our test environment after packaging and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

[Copy to slave plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) also copies files back from slaves to the master. Might be worth the look.