# VSTS build agent on another machine than jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a VSTS project with GIT as SCM.

I have an on-premise build machine with the VSTS agent configured (says server1).

I have a jenkins server on another on-premise machine (says server2).

The get sources is done on server1. I then use the "Queue Jenkins Job" task to trigger a build with the jenkins project name (project is configured on jenkins server, maybe badly).

But how can the source code moves from server1 to server2 ? How can my jenkins job knows where to find the source code to build ?

Comment: You can use copy slave plugin for this and copy the files required to master work space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the source during Jenkins build tool by using [Team Foundation Server Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin).

If you need to use source files on different server, you can copy files from remote server. Some related threads:

[How to copy file from SSH remote host to Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259811/how-to-copy-file-from-ssh-remote-host-to-jenkins-server)

[How to copy file from remote host to jenkins server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259899/how-to-copy-file-from-remote-host-to-jenkins-server)

Comment: ok, so, get sources should not be done by vsts but by jenkins ; can be ok for my use case