# send files or execute commands over ssh

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins is running on windows machine and I am trying to copy files from windows to unix as a build step.

SSH sever details has been configured in the global configuration and connected successfully.

kindly share the Exec command to copy files from windows to unix

Comment: Can you clarify, is your unix machine a jenkins slave? In that case you can use the plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin If its just some random unix server, to push stuff via ssh to it, the unix machine needs a ssh server running. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259811/how-to-copy-file-from-ssh-remote-host-to-jenkins-server

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of ssh client on your windows. I suggest Winscp, which is simple, easy and fast.
Winscp is a GUI application but as you want to run something from Jenkins you need to have a command line tool. Good news is that you can run Winscp in command line. Then the following steps should answer your question:

1. Install Winscp on the Windows machine.
2. Add your Winscp installation path (sth like C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP) to your system environment path variable
3. Now you should be able to run winscp command in windows command prompt
4. The command below will copy the file, you should read winscp manual for more details:

   **winscp root:password@UNIX_MACHINE_IP /command "put c:/PATH_TO_FILE_ON_WINDOWS /home/PATH_TO_TARGET_ON_UNIX"**

Comment: Putty's pscp is worth a look too if you want it really lightweight.

Comment: @sampath cool! then maybe you can mark my post as answer so others can use this as well

Answer (score 1):

There is a Jenkins plugin that might fit your needs:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin

It uses [Java SSH library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) so no need to install another SSH client.

Answer (score 0):

To copy files using PuTTY or any unix shell powered with SSH from windows, run this command.

```
scp /path/to/file.ext user@m192.168.0.100:/Destiny/path
```

To run commands in your remote computer just connect to it with:

```
ssh user@192.168.0.100
```

Customize the user, the IP and authenticate with the properly password.

Comment: if `scp` command is not available in **PuTTY**, try with `pscp`