# How to copy file from SSH remote host to Jenkins Server. sshpass doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, ssh, terminal

How to copy file from SSH remote host to Jenkins Server? 
I've found one solution here:
[How to copy file from SSH remote host to Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259811/how-to-copy-file-from-ssh-remote-host-to-jenkins-server)

But when I try sshpass in Execute shell step - nothing happens. Nothing in Console output.

Can somebody advise, maybe there is some plugin for this purpose?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy file from SSH remote host to Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259811/how-to-copy-file-from-ssh-remote-host-to-jenkins-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason in my case was that I had wrong paths. When I corrected paths in script, everything has just worked fine.